Using "deblack" to clean messy videos with black flickering, getting [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long
I'm using the repository found here https://github.com/FarisHijazi/deblack/tree/master, which should fix my problem, I have installed ffmpeg, deblack itself and python is correctly installed, however, when I run the code (also using the correct directory/path to video) the error of [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long is popping up, the path I'm calling here is E:\Cleanup and I'm not that tech savvy, so I'm wondering what's causing this problem
Tried changing directories/folders to see if it would go away, it didn't. Anything else is beyond my thinking abilities and searches barely show up the git repository.
